# existsById and findById performance in Mongo db

Tags: mongodb

Which performs better. 
Is existsById and findById to find the id in the Collection of Mongodb?.
Also, suggests me in finding the best documentation to go through the optimization techniques in MongoDB.

Comment: What is `existsById`? What API are you using?

Answer (score 2):

It's probably very similar since both are read operations and using ids, which are indexed to give a better performance.
If you want to have a real idea of which method is better **for you**, you can analyze your specific query in you code. Here are some details : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/analyze-query-plan/index.html

Otherwise, if you want o more in-depth learning, there is a free course on MongoDB University (a MongoDB official website) about performance : https://university.mongodb.com/courses/catalog